# Applying a hex value color style.background-color

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, background-color

I'm trying to apply a color on my navbar in ionic but i have no luck. This is my code.

```
 <ion-header>
   <ion-navbar [style.color]="(xdg|async)?.color">//outputs hex ex. #dda63a
     <ion-title>xdg</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

But it does not apply to the navbar. I also tried passing the data in my navParams:

```
//<ion-navbar [style.color]="xdgColor">
this.xdgColor = this.navParams.get('xdgColor')
console.log(this.xdgColor)//#dda63a
```

Also no luck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should be `xdgColor` as `[style.color]="xdgColor"` because you don't have  `color` as a property in your `xdgColor` object

Comment: i also tried that but no luck

Comment: are you available in teamviewer or remote desktop. so that I can debug and help you

Comment: sorry but im not. just using someone else's laptop

Comment: chrome extension is easy to use not possible?

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the title text or the background color of the navbar itself?
You mentioned style.background-color as well as style.color

Comment: @99tharun the background color of the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.ts**

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar [style.background-color]="xdgColor">
     <ion-title>xdg</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Ionic creates another div inside ion-navbar to set the background-color. You can override this by adding the below css to your **app.scss** file:

```
.header .toolbar-background{
    background: none;
}
```

Now, since you've disabled the background-color set by ionic, you can set a default background color for your navbar by adding this css too to your **app.scss**

```
ion-navbar.toolbar
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```